# D3 conic projections - invert when parallels are southern

Tags: javascript, d3.js, projection

I currently have a problem with D3 conic projections (ex: conicEqualArea, conicConformal).

When the parallels selected are under 0 (ex : -35 and -50), the invert function does not seem to work.

Example:

```
var p = d3.geo.conicEqualArea().parallels([-35,-50])

p.invert([480,250])
// Result : Array [ -268.7327478371507, -0 ], whereas expected value would be [0,0]

p([-268.7327478371507,-0])
// Result : Array [715.2876827794818, 388.95968864688876], so projection and invert are not coherent
```

How can I get a working invert function in these conditions ?